# Reciprocal a number and then reciprocal it again to the original number

Tags: c#, windows, function, calculator

Working on a Calculator(Windows look-alike/Exact to be specific :P) for some time. Designing it exact same.

And about programming, i have a problem It's a major one **When i reciprocal 6 the result is "0.1666666666666667" which is i also get, but when i reciprocal it("0.1666666666666667") it again i get "5.99999999999999"** how to solve this problem?

Right one's mine.

https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-mJbRF59fgV8/Uksb9_5zFxI/AAAAAAAAADQ/loEiJtCAfp4/w346-h244/HelpCommunity.png

---

Thanks for the answers. i appriciate it.

Can i do like this?

```
    double chk;
    void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        if (chk == 0) {
            chk = 1 / Convert.ToDouble(txtResult.Text);
            txtResult.Text = chk.ToString();
        }
        else{
            chk = 1 / chk;
            txtResult.Text = chk.ToString();
        }           
    }
```

Comment: [Just read this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) and you'll understand ....

Comment: Numbers have finite precision so you cant really have (1/x) * x == 1 always be true no matter what numeric type you pick. You will likely have less trouble if you pick a type like decimal rather than float or double but the problem you describe cannot be solved exactly just using some basic number type. You would have to implement some kind of analytic solution engine.

Comment: don't calculate and round, store irrational numbers as binomials. `(1/6) != 0.166666666667`.

Comment: @Jodrell <pedantic> actually `1/6` is *not* irrational [by definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_number) </pedantic>

Comment: @RogerRowland, spot on, I actually mean rational numbers, since thay can be stored as a ratio. The clue is in the name.

Comment: @SumitMandal I deleted my answer, because based on your comment I realized you did not do any research on the matter. Calculators are very often used as programming assignments in school, and there is widespread documentation and examples. Please try to research on your on, at least the basics, before posting a question.

Comment: @nestedloop no worries. But i tried that, but got no success, if a got the idea how to do this **("recipro(reciproc(6))")** then it would help me to complete my sqrt function. The **code** i'm asking is for the equation above on the calculator. eg if i press 9 then press square root 3 times the equation would be :- **sqrt(sqrt(sqrt(9)))**. The result of the equation i'll find. Do you know how can i do that? or any Article? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just worried about the inversion not roundtripping, you can do something cheeky like this:

```
Dictionary<double, double> reciprocals = new Dictionary<double, double>(); 

private double Reciprocal(double val)
{
    double reciprocal;
    if (reciprocals.TryGetValue(val, out reciprocal))
    {
        return reciprocal;
    }

    reciprocal = 1 / val;
    reciprocals[reciprocal] = val;
    return reciprocal;
}
```

which gives you

```
var r1 = this.Reciprocal(6d); // = 0.1666...
var r2 = this.Reciprocal(r1); // = 6.0
```

Answer (score 1):

All the answers are pretty good, so I'm just going to add a different thing:

Since floats and doubles, and even decimals have limited precision, you're never going to get the original value back reliably. However, you can use this to your advantage too - basically, you should round the resulting number to a given precision. This will round the number from 5.99999 back to 6 (the decimal places are fake precision anyway).

It all comes down to what kind of precision you really need. Is this enough? Great. Would you rather like fixed decimal precision? Use `decimal`. Do you absolutely need 100% precision? You have to use rationals (ie. storing the number as two integers, 1 and 6). You're going to get into trouble as soon as you use non-rational operations, such as (some) square roots etc., but that's all very dependent on what you're actually trying to do.

Note that even using the stack approach is going to be tricky if you allow other operations than multiplication and division - it's hard to make a calculator that appears to be "mathematical".

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Complex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.complex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) type to perform the operation.

or alternatively create your own number representation as below.

---

If you had this type

```
struct Binomial
{
    public int Numerator
    public int Denominator
}
```

You could then implement the appropriate operators to perform the mathematical functions you require.

For instance

```
struct Binomial
{
    public int Numerator
    public int Denominator

    public static Binomial operator /(int numerator, int denominator)
    {
        return new Binomial
        {
            Numerator = numerator,
            Denominator = deniminator
        };   
    }

    public static Binomial operator /(int numerator, Binomial denominator)
    {
        return new Binomial
        {
            Numerator = numerator * deominator.Denominator,
            Denominator = deomninator.Numerator
        };
    }

    public static Binomial operator /(Binomial numerator, int denominator)
    {
        numerator.Denominator *= denominator;
        return numerator;
    }
}
```

Should allow you to perform the divisions you need for reciprication. I leave the `ToString()` override as an excercise for the reader.

This would allow

```
Binomial sixth = 1 / 6;
Binomial roundtrip = 6 / sixth;
```

but, to make the type useful you'd need to implement equality, other mathematical and cast operators.